# SQL query to fetch data form another table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I've been trying to build a little complex SQL query to fetch some keys from a table which has no relation with the one in which I need to "ask".

Practical case:

I have four tables: users, devices, preferences and user_devices.

- Table users, there are user information and the user "ID".
- Table devices, there are columns with device information, the device "ID" (device ID) and the device "key" (device internal ID).
- Table preferences, "user ID" and some boolean fields with weekdays (monday, tuesday, wednesday...).
- Table user_devices, assign ID (auto_increment, not important), "user_id" and "device_id" with relations to their respective tables. This tabble is used to assign a device to a user.

The thing is that I need to obtain all the "devices.key" of users that have the preference "monday" set to true in table preferences.

Example: I ask the database for devices with preference monday true and I obtain an array with two device key.

This query fetch the device key of the user 4, but I need to fetch de device key of all the users with "monday" set to true (1) in the database.

`SELECT key FROM devices, user_devices WHERE devices.id = user_devices.device_id AND user_devices.user_id = 4`

Thank you very much.

Comment: You can try a JOIN function, maybe it will help you.

Comment: I've tried to JOIN preferences.id and user_devices.user_id but I don't know exactly how to adapt the query with JOIN to my needs... :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can try following query

```
SELECT `devices`.`key` 
FROM users 
JOIN preferences ON users.id = preferences.user_id
JOIN user_devices ON users.id = user_devices.user_id
JOIN devices ON user_devices.device_id = devices.id
WHERE preferences.monday = true
```

obviously you'll have to check and correct the column names of preferences and users table in query to match your database column names.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this (i just hate JOINs ;p):

```
SELECT DISTINCT(`devices`.`key`)
FROM `devices`,`user_devices`,`preferences`
WHERE `devices`.`id` = `user_devices`.`device_id`
  AND `preferences`.`user_id` = `user_devices`.`user_id`
  AND `preferences`.`monday` = 1
```

Hope it would help